# Content inside a table cell doesn't take the whole space

Tags: html, css

I created this table:

```css
table {

}

thead {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

tbody, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell-first-column {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;  
}

.cell, th {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
}

.td-cell {
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.chart {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0
}

.chart-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: gold;
}

.cell-text {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="cell-first-column">Alfreds Futterkiste</div></td>
    <td><div class="cell">Maria Anders</div></td>
    <td><div class="cell">Germany</div></td>
    <td><div class="cell">1234567</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="cell-first-column">Centro comercial</div></td>
    <td><div class="cell">Francisco Chang</div></td>
    <td><div class="cell">Mexico</div></td>
    <td><div class="cell">1234567</div></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><div class="cell-first-column">Opla</div></td>
    <td class="td-cell">
      <div class="chart">
        <div class="chart-inner" style="height: 90%"></div>
        <div class="cell-text">Charles Boule</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td-cell">
      <div class="chart">
        <div class="chart-inner" style="height: 30%"></div>
        <div class="cell-text">France</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="td-cell">
      <div class="chart">
        <div class="chart-inner" style="height: 50%"></div>
        <div class="cell-text">1234567</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

inside the third row, the cells are colored and to do that I use `absolute` position.
It works but I don't understand why the yellow doesn't take the entire cell space, there is a white margin between the yellow and the cell border.
Margins are 0.

How it is now vs How I would like it to be:

[image]

Why? How can I solve?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Because they have heights set? In your example it looks good to me, no gap to the top or to the sides.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't color the `td` instead of the div inside ?

Comment: @debugger I need the cell have a specific width and height so I don't need to set the table width to 100%

Comment: @Cédric because of not the whole cell should be coloured as you can see in my working example. And also because inside the cell should be also the text that need to be centered

Comment: @niorad  I need the cell have a specific width and height

Comment: @huanfeng in the cells of the third row there is like a barchart, the percentage value is dynamic and could be anything between 0% and 100%. Depends on some data

Comment: If you mean the very small white space between yellow and border, then set the padding of td to 0 should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way:

```
<table cellpadding="0">
```

Answer (score 2):

Set padding of td to 0 should fix the issue.